# How to replace negative margins with transform to achieve paper folding effect?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm attempting to implement a paper folding effect using CSS only. I achieved the desired effect visually (almost), with some major flaws; namely:

- The use of box-shadow and negative margins slows down performance considerably.
- Negative margins do not synchronize with the transform transition and end up overlapping list items somewhere between the transition begin and end.

What I need help with:

- **Important**: Replace the negative margins with transform styling that helps achieve the desired folding effect more realistically, improving performance and removing the overlapping elements created by the negative margins. The problem is having all the elements unfold out and fold back behind the *Menu* button, since transform moves the elements relative to their own original spaces, not affecting other elements through their movements, leaving their spaces present.
- **Optional**: Replacing box-shadow with an alternative way to simulate the light hitting the edges and then fading inside the fold, with the light coming through the screen, where the user is, in order to improve performance, perhaps through the use of opacity and pseudo classes.

I've noticed every pair is already connected and *linked* if I remove the margins and watch them fold without moving, thanks to the transform origin. Perhaps there's a way to achieve this to link both elements above and under the element. You may remove the negative margins and run it to understand what I mean.

```js
$('#menu-main-toggle').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');      
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
/* Aesthetic Styling Begin */
ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none}#menu-main,#menu-main-toggle{width:75%;margin:auto}#menu-main-toggle,.menu-item{background:#e74c3c;border:none}#menu-main .menu-link,#menu-main-toggle{outline:0;display:block;height:50px;padding:12px;color:#fff;border-top:1px dashed #bf2718;box-sizing:border-box;text-decoration:none;text-align:center}
/* Aesthetic Styling End */

#nav-primary .dropdown-toggle.active + .toggleable > .menu-item {
    margin: 0;
    transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 0 transparent;
}

#menu-main .menu-item {
    transition: transform .75s ease-in-out, margin .75s ease-in-out, box-shadow .75s ease-in-out;
}
#menu-main .menu-item.odd {
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -50px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
#menu-main .menu-item.even {
    margin-top: -100px;
    transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom;
    box-shadow: inset 0 50px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="nav-primary" class="text-center">
  <button id="menu-main-toggle" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu</button>
  <ul id="menu-main" class="toggleable">
    <li class="menu-item odd">
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Lorem</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item even">
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item odd">
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Situs Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item even">
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Consectetur</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item odd">
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Duis</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item even">
      <a class="menu-link" href="#">Vivamus</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a posible solution.

I have tested it only in Chrome, since it's using variables it needs a modern browser. But you can adapt it easily to work without variables.

The transforms used are **hard**. I will try to explain them later  ..

Hover on the list to fold it

```css
.test {
 --height: 150px;
 --time: 5s;
 --angle: 0deg;
 --angle2: -0deg;
 --bkg1: 0%;
 --bkg2: 100%;
}

.test:hover {
 --angle: 90deg;
 --angle2: -90deg;
 --bkg1: 100%;
 --bkg2: 0%;
}

ul {
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 70%;
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 transition: transform var(--time);
 bottom:  0px;
 transform: rotateX(var(--angle)) translateY(100%) rotateX(var(--angle2));
}

li:nth-child(1) {
 height: 0px;
}
li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(3) {
 height: calc(2 * var(--height));
}
li:nth-child(4), li:nth-child(5) {
 height: calc(4 * var(--height));
}
li:nth-child(6), li:nth-child(7) {
 height: calc(6 * var(--height));
}

a {
 position: absolute;
 height: var(--height);
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 font-size: 40px;
 background-size: 100% 300%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 transition: transform var(--time), background-position var(--time);
}

li:nth-child(odd) a {
 top: 100%;
 transform-origin: top;
 transform: rotateX(var(--angle)) translateY(100%) perspective(400px) translateY(-100%) rotateX(var(--angle2)) rotateX(var(--angle2));
 background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 30%, transparent 66%);
 background-position: center var(--bkg1);
}
li:nth-child(even) a {
 bottom: 0px;
 transform-origin: bottom;
 transform: rotateX(var(--angle2)) translateY(-100%) perspective(400px) translateY(100%) rotateX(var(--angle)) rotateX(var(--angle));
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 30%, transparent 66%);
 background-position: center var(--bkg2);
}

li:nth-child(1) a {
 background-color: rgba(200,0,0,0.3);
}
li:nth-child(2) a {
 background-color: rgba(0,200,0,0.3);
}
li:nth-child(3) a {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,200,0.3);
}
li:nth-child(4) a {
 background-color: rgba(200,200,0,0.3);
}
li:nth-child(5) a {
 background-color: rgba(200,0,200,0.3);
}
li:nth-child(6) a {
 background-color: rgba(0,200,200,0.3);
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
   <li>
      <a>-1-</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>-2-</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>-3-</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>-4-</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>-5-</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>-6-</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Let's try to explain the transforms.

To make things a little bit easier, I am using 2 elements to achieve the transform: the base li will handle the Y movement, the a will handle the own  rotation.

For a given element, the amount of Y translation is given by the rotation of the elements that are on top of it. This can be reproduced by a single element , with the same height of the sum of those elements, rotating at the same pace.

In the first moment, the li is placed at Y = 0. Then it is rotated, then translated the same amount as it's height, and counter-rotated since we only want this element to achieve the Y position and not the rotation.

For the a element, this is harder :-( . We want it to rotate, and to do it in perspective. But I have been unable to adjust the following elements to this case, so I need it to be a *fake* perspective. This perspective will shrink the element width, but not the height. There are 2 points that, in the case of a rotation, keep unaltered by it: the rotation axis and the perspective point. So I need to first move the element to it's rotating border, apply here the perspective, go back to where it was, and then apply the final rotation.

The last 2 rotations are solving a problem with the CSS variables. I needed

```
rotateX(calc( 2 * var(--angle)))
```

but this seems to be too much for Chrome.

Comment: That's fantastic. Never knew about CSS vars and counters until you showed me your answer. I'm giving it more time, though, because I would rather not give up on the other browsers just yet. If there is no other solution I'll choose your answer and try to work it in.

Comment: Notice that the core of the solution doesn't need variables. You can change all the places where var() is used with data of your choice. I just used it to make it more clear what was going on, and to change it as you want.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I tried to get the code but I've yet to understand the use of so many translates and rotates for the same element's transformation. I'd appreciate it if you could explain some things and perhaps point me in the right direction as to how you achieved the result to go read or research to learn more on my own. Also, I tried testing its performance on Chrome's dev tools and, if I'm right, it was very good, but I'd like for you to confirm it performs well in case I did something wrong. You're also right, I can replace all calc's and val's with my own values.

Comment: I have tried to explain it . But I know that my explanations aren't good, my English isn't good enough ... Also, yes, the performance (even all the expensive calculus) is good, as it's achieved by the GPU (and those are usually good at this kind of things)

Comment: Much appreciated for everything. I'll take from here on out.

Comment: sorry to bother, but I have been trying to understand what you did. I got it, but I wish to learn how to do it on my own. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction? Searching for "advanced css transforms" and "complex css transforms" does not yield the results that I am looking for. Where may I be able to learn what you were able to accomplish?

Comment: No worry. This is beyond the usual use of css transforms, so it's not surprising that you don't find much info. I learned a lot about transforms using OpenGL or WebGL. The transforms used there are usually one level beyond those used in CSS. But usually you won't need those level for day to day use in the web.